# Start Tor Browser maximized

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I start the Tor Browser Bundle, I need to manually maximize it every time. Is there a way to make it just start maximized?

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so which version of Windows are you using and which version of the browser bundle?

Comment: I'm using Tor Browser 4.0 on Linux.

Comment: What window manager or desktop environment are you using? Could it maybe be a setting of that?

Comment: No, it's the application itself that takes care of remembering the window's position. Firefox (not Tor) for example does it fine under the same OS.

Comment: This quesiton has nothing to do with Tor except that you're using TBB. This has to do with your window compositor and would probably be a better fit on other SE sites (or a quick search).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is the right reason but some time ago I read (I think at the [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)-documentation) that the browser always starts with the same resolution (and you shouldn't resize it) to make your browser less track-able.
You can start a good privacy-test at http://ip-check.info and have a look at the "screen"-lines.