# Tor Browser is not maximizing

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have just downloaded Tor Browser in Debian GNU/Linux system, but after an hour of use, the window does not maximize. When clicking on the maximize button or double-clicking the title bar, in a matter of 1/3 of second the window maximizes but comes back to normal. Before it happened I have installed Flash Plugin and enabled it in the configurations, then it started.

For now I need to drag the window and touch the top of the screen for the browser maximize in the laterals, because I am using Xfce, and just grab the edge of the window and pull down, but I would like to know what could have happened, if it has a bug with Flash, my system or what.

Comment: maybe a related question: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4381/5234

Answer (score 1):

I feel you answer your own question with:

> Before it happened I have installed Flash Plugin and enabled it in the
>   configurations, then it started.

Installing flash it not recommended.

I would suggest downloading a clean copy of browser bundle, then test again.
If it still happens then I suggest you submit a ticket to the [bugtracker](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor).